# How to change access to the google drive photo programmatically from android?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have an app. With its help I can upload images on google drive. The issue is that only google logged-in users see it. How I can programmatically make uploaded images with public access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Drive API [Permission.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) to create permission for your uploaded file in Google Drive.

When you upload a file using drive api get the `file id` from the [File Resourse](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) in the response body. Then use [Permission.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) to share the file publicly.

### Sample Request Body:

File Id: `1P8vNKbOXGlzity4ZvAjEpfMDEH_xxxxxx`

```
{
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "anyone"
}
```

### Sample Response Body:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#permission",
 "id": "anyoneWithLink",
 "type": "anyone",
 "role": "reader",
 "allowFileDiscovery": false
}
```

### Output:

- By using this link format `https://drive.google.com/file/d/<file id>/view` you can view the uploaded image even if you are not logged in with your Google account.

[image]

Comment: My incognito shows the Tagalog word `Mag-sign In` which basically means Sign-In